# How onInitialized works in Bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

Very simple example : https://jsfiddle.net/x6z6w0n8/8/

How can I set selected values on Initialization step without creating duplicate?

Sample from off site works well. https://jsbin.com/yupinelefa/edit?html,js,console

---

As I noticed, in off-example they don't initialize select, they just use event `onInitialized`. But when I initialize (set options) to select in `onInitialized` event then nothing is changed, I also have 2 selects.

---

In general - I have `bootstrap-multiselect` on page. OnInitialization I want to set selected values in it. 
I have next code as example :

```
<select id="example-onInitialized" multiple="multiple" class="multiple">
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
     <option value="4">Option 4</option>
     <option value="5">Option 5</option>
     <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>

$('.multiselect').multiselect({
            onInitialized: function(select, container) {
               $(select).multiselect('select', 2); // I want to select item with value '2'
         }
});
```

But this script creates one additional select. So as result I have one select with selected value '2' and one empty select. 
For me it seems like every call of `.multiselect()` will create new select. Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, please check my update. Hope now it is more understandable. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6z6w0n8/10/)**.

That happen because `select` is an option that should be called always on `.multiselect()` (that initialize the plugin), so in your case your plugin will be initilized for the second time when you will use it.

> **`onInitialized()`** is a function which is triggered when the multiselect is finished initializing.

The `select` option is made to select also the given values after initialization of the plugin, so you could just use it like :

```
$('.multiple').multiselect('select', 2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, initializing `select` in one "chaine" solve my problem.